# SdFat write floats to file ESP32

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32, sd-card

I Need to write float or Strings value into the SDVolume Cache in SDFAT library, I'm using ESP32 with SdCard module.

```
  uint8_t* pCache = (uint8_t*)sd.vol()->cacheClear();
  memset(pCache, ' ', 512);
  for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 512; i += 4) {
    
    pCache[i + 0] = 'r'; // I Need to write a Float value or String into this cell
    pCache[i + 1] = ',';
    pCache[i + 2] = '0';
    pCache[i + 3] = '\n';
  }
```

Libray link: https://github.com/greiman/SdFat

Comment: is this C or C++? Can't be both. Is this using the Arduino platform or not? Can't tell from your code, but it doesn't look like it. **Please don't use "random" tags"**; unrelated tags will just lead to experts ignoring your question.

Comment: It's Arduino, but in general the library is written with C++. So we are talking about C++ and Arduino platform. Tags updated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First:

> ```
> // I Need to write a Float value or String into this cell
> ```

makes no sense - that "cell" is a single character, like `'e'`. How do you write a full float value into a single character?

You probably just want to fill `pCache` with a string representation of your float. So do that!

We've got all C++ at our disposal, so let's use a somewhat memory efficient method:

[`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) is the C++ way to convert numeric values to strings. Something like

```cpp
#include <charconv>
…
    std::to_chars(pCache, pCache+512-1, floatvalue);
```

would be appropriate.

Couple of things:

- You need to *zero-terminate* strings if your needs to be able to know where they end. So, instead of `memset(pCache, ' ', 512)`, `memset(pCache, 0, 512)`; would be more sensible.
- Are you sure your even using the right functions? `vol()->cacheClear()` is pretty unambigously marked as "do not use in your application" [here](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat/blob/fb7415151b04bd060e97de08767dff06f1c26c27/src/ExFatLib/ExFatPartition.h#L72)! It also seems to be very unusual to me that you would write your string to some block device cache instead of getting a buffer for a file from the file system, or passing a buffer to the file system to write to a file.

Comment: My application needs to log data into a file with a high frequency using buffers like you said, could you suggest any solution to do that, I need to log 1 kHz to a file.
These lines may contain strings. how can I replace the device cache with a buffer.

Comment: 1 kHz is not "high frequency". And again, you're trying to put a string into a `char`, that very literally makes no sense, I can't fix your idea of what a string or a character is for you! And you really should not replace the device cache with a buffer - that makes no sense, either, you need that cache to be able to write regularly.

Comment: Plus, it's *never* a good idea to convert floats to strings for storage if you need high rate. Simply make that file a binary file and if necessary, convert the floats to strings when reading, not when writing on a resource-limited device to a bandwidth-limited storage medium.

Comment: I answered exactly that in my answer. You take a buffer, you use `std::to_chars` on it, you hand it to your file system.

Comment: Std::to_chars is recognized unfortunately by Arduino.

Comment: @KhalidSghir you said you had C++, and `std::to_chars` is part of C++. Have you maybe set an old standard version of C++ in your compiler? Should be C++17 or newer, which is the default on most compilers by now.

Comment: I have Arduino and it is written normally in C++, but I'm getting an error " exit status 1 'to_chars' is not a member of 'std'.

Comment: See the comment you replied to,.

Comment: I still get the error maybe because I'm calling it from the .ino file.

Comment: sorry, can't remotely fix your build setup from here. I'm also a bit confused you're using a third-party SD / Fat library – the underlying ESP32 library that ESP32-arduino builds upon has a better-tested, more mature SDcard / FAT library in itself.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and time, when I write Raw Data using the cache example above, it's working fine with Integers with a high speed my need is to write floats instead of integers. Maybe I should get more knowledge about data types in C++.